# Angular routing with query parameters

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, url-routing

I'm currently building on Angular: 7.2.14 and wanted to see if someone could explain how to redirect query parameters either with a route guard, shared service or other means etc.

The problem I'm trying to solve requires query parameters to come in from the root Uri path then redirect the route to the correct child component keeping the query intact when the router changes Uris.

For example, say you had an outside href linked into an angular app (see routes below) and the original route href is: `domain.com?foo=bar`, since this is the root route of `''` angular will then transfer the route over to the matching child route `''` this in turn redirects to `'login'`. The end result lands you here `domain.com/#/login` and my query of `?foo=bar` is lost.

How do you create a route, route-guard or even a service etc. and maintain the original query but also redirecting you to the final location of `domain.com/#/login?foo=bar` starting from the root path?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
  path: '', component: AuthorizeComponent,
  children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login'  },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuardService] },
    { path: 'confirm', component: ConfirmComponent, canActivate: [ConfirmGuardService] },
    { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
  ]
}];
```

I will try to show my setup here. I do have a `LoginGuardService` which implements `canActivate` and within the canActivate function I can redirect keeping the query together by using `router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: route.queryParams })`, except this ONLY works when you link directly to the route like `domain.com/#/login?foo=bar` not to the root first.

**LoginGuardService**

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    if (this.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.router.navigate(['/confirm'], { queryParams: route.queryParams });
   } else {
      return true;
   }

}
```

**ConfirmGuardService**

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

   if (!this.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
     this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: route.queryParams });
   } else {
     return true;
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Set `queryParamsHandling: 'preserve'` in your navigation extras ([Resource](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras)):

```js
this.router.navigate(['/confirm'], { queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' });
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this solves my query parameters from being lost, how are you suggesting I use the router.navigation with my routes outlined above? I'm asking because the issue appears only when you navigate from the `AuthorizeComponent` route of `''` which redirects you to the route `'login'`. Thanks.

Comment: After more research I found additional information regarding this issue.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12664

Comment: I had the exact same requirement in my project and solved this issue by using this workaround. You should use `queryParamsHandling: 'preserve'` in each router navigation till the landing router. Can you provide a Stackblitz example, so I can look into it better? I think minor changes in routes definition also might help.